# Load Emacs Minor only for specific Major

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, ruby-mode

I am pretty new to emacs and I have installed a 'starter kit' for Ruby on Rails, which works nicely. However, I am also developing in PHP and the starter brings about some problems.

I want to switch off some of the minor modes when editing all files other than ruby files.

in my .emacs file I have:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ruby-block")
(require 'ruby-block)
```

If I comment this out then the minor disappears for all files so I tried adding a hook (although I am a complete beginner so this might be the wrong approach) like so:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook (lambda () (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ruby-block")))
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook (lambda () (require 'ruby-block)))
```

I also tried using the event hook to call a function and moving the lines above into a function but still couldn't get this to work.

I would really appreciate any help removing the ruby-block minor from all files other than .rb

Comment: It's almost always better to define a function and use the function name in your add-hook call, rather than a lambda expression, because that way you can make+evaluate changes to the function and they will automatically be used when the hook next runs (as opposed to removing and re-adding lambda expressions every time you make a change).

Comment: @phils, it's even possible to say `(add-hook 'some-hook (defun my-func () ...))` because `defun` returns the name of the function it just defined.

Comment: cjm: Ha. That's a neat trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used `ruby-block-mode`, but I had remove it.

here is what I setting for `ruby-block-mode`, give it a try:

```
(eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
  '(progn
    (require 'ruby-block)
    (ruby-block-mode t)
    (setq ruby-block-highlight-toggle t)))
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks, spent hours trying to get this working, your code worked straight away. Just had to add the load path to ruby-block above (require 'ruby-block)

Comment: At the first glance after you restart your emacs, the RBlock may still on the mode-line, try to C-n or something else to move the point, the RBlock will disappeared. It's a strange behavior, that's why I remove it. Actually, I don't think it useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the two lines you mention are necessary for the minor-modes (btw: which?) to work, they are not responsible for turning the minor-modes on. The first one:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ruby-block")
```

just extends a path-variable, i.e., where Emacs will look for code to load, while the second one:

```lisp
(require 'ruby-block)
```

reads some library code, i.e., mostly function definitions.

The actual mode invocation would probably look more like this:

```lisp
(ruby-block-mode t)
```

You were on the right path with using the `'ruby-mode-hook` but you don't have to worry about the `load-path` nor the `(require...)`. They can stay as they are, i.e., no need to comment them out. Instead, find the actual invocation of the minor mode and put it in your `(lambda ()...)` declaration and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I searched my .emacs file for (ruby-block-mode t) and strangely I found that it is already inside a 'ruby-mode-hook'. So now I am even more confused as to why ruby-block-mode is enabled when editing PHP files.